# First request to node.js app on Windows Azure with MongoDB yields 400 Bad Request

Tags: node.js, mongodb, azure, mongoose

I'm using Windows Azure to deploy a node.js application that I've written that exposes a fairly simple REST CRUD api to clients.  Its hosted in a Windows Azure Website and uses MongoDB through the Windows Azure store with mongoose.   The requests I'm making to the service are JSON and the responses are JSON (not sure that matters but others have talked about 400 responses to requests with a Content-Type of application/json)

On the first access in a long while, the application returns 400 Bad Request without fail.   As long as I keep the application "warm" by hitting it frequently (at least once a minute or so) - I never seem to get this again.

It doesn't matter on the hosting scaling setting - I get the same thing on the free tier as in reserved mode.

Anyone else seen this?

Comment: This may have to do with automatic recycling in IIS.  If inactive, the hosting process is recycled, so you have lost whatever state (likely your mongodb connection).  You might try some sort of connection keepalive, or code to recover from a broken connection in your app

Comment: Did you check logs and request for more information about error ?

Comment: Have you tried mocking the MongoDB part and checking if it still returns 400 on the first request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to guarantee access to any connection in node.js, you have to put all code that requires a connection inside of the callback. The way that mongoose exposes this connection is through an event. When the event 'open' is called by the mongoose connection, then you have access to a database connection.

I.E.

```
mongoose.connect('details');

mongoose.on('open', function () {
  var connection = mongoose.connection;

  // Do things with your connection here
  doThings(connection);
});

function doThings(connection) {
  app.get(...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you had a code snippet, but my guess is that your connection to mongo is happening asynchronously and your site is serving the request before the connection is actually open.

I tested this scenario and couldn't reproduce the issue. You can see my code here: https://github.com/ntotten/azure-mongo-sample

Basically, I am using mongoose to connect and the connection is happening right away when the app is loaded. You can see the code below.

app.js:

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , user = require('./routes/user')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path');

var TaskList = require('./routes/tasklist');
var taskList = new TaskList(process.env.CUSTOMCONNSTR_MONGOLAB_URI);

...
```

tasklist.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , task = require('../models/task.js');


module.exports = TaskList;


function TaskList(connection) {
  mongoose.connect(connection);
}

...
```

Comment: Thanks Nathan - I tried your approach and I can still repro the issue.   My code is here https://github.com/timfpark/nodejs-azure-mongodb